# How to render video stream to a unity texture using Metal?

Tags: ios, graphics, metal

I am working on a project which requires me to render a video stream(Byte Buffer) on a unity texture, I was able to do that for android by passing the unity texture id to my android plugin and then using OpenGL ES to bind the texture and eventually updating it with the buffers. I now have to do something similar for iOS, which brings Metal into the picture, anyone has any reference I can use? I am not looking for an exact solution since that would be too much to ask, but anything pointing me in the right direction would be great!

Comment: I was able to get the RTCMTLVideoView, but not sure how to find the RTCVideoFrame data which is needed since I need to send the data to Unity.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly your problem is, could you please provide more details.

Comment: Hi @HamidYusifli, let me elaborate it further, I get a UI View from webrtc which needs to be rendered on a surface. If it was a pure ios app, it would be straightforward, since I can just add it to a UIView Stack. But I am trying to create an app in unity for ios. So I need to render it on a unity surface. Passing the unity texture pointer to the native side( Android or ios) would be one way, but that is not possible since Metal textures do not let you touch the memory of the texture. So the other way would be to extract the frame from this webrtc view and send it to unity to render them.

Comment: The statement "Metal textures do not let you touch the memory of the texture" is not accurate. My answer shows how to access bytes to and from MTLTextures.

Comment: According to Apple documentation, "Metal manages memory for textures and doesn’t provide you direct access to it. So you can’t get a pointer to the texture data in memory and copy the pixels yourself. Instead, you call methods on an MTLTexture object to copy data from memory you can access into the texture and vice versa." My goal was to get the pointer to the texture data instead of the texture data itself.

Answer (score 0):

**MTLTexture -> Unity**

(1) Create MTLTexture using the same format as the Unity Texture.

(2) Get the bytes from the above texture:

```
MTLTexture.getBytes(_:bytesPerRow:from:mipmapLevel:
```

(3) Pass the bytes to Unity

**Unity -> MTLTexture**

(1) Get pointer to Unity bytes

(2) Create MTLTexture using the same format as the Unity Texture.

(3) Replace MTLTexture with bytes:

```
MTLTexture.replace(region:mipmapLevel:slice:withBytes:bytesPerRow:bytesPerImage:)
```